# Vaadin, applying own theme doesn't work

Tags: java, sass, vaadin

I am trying to add custom theme to my Vaadin 7 project. I used the Vaadin plug-in theme creater, it created the necessary files and I included a simple background-color setting to my table, but even though reindeer theme is included it doesn't seem to work. After I apply my theme with `@Theme()` annotation on my UI class my table disappears and I get this (without the custom theme it looks fine):

[image]

I read the part of the Book of Vaadin that describes this (https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html) but it still doesn't work for me.
I read this part: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html#figure.themes.theme-contents and it shows reindeer should be under themes, but it says I have to include the vaadin-themes.jar and it will work fine. I did add it, my filestructure looks like this:

[image]

airlinedb_customtheme.scss file's code:

```
@import "../reindeer/reindeer.scss";
@mixin airlinedb_customtheme {
  @include reindeer;
  .v-table {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

and my theme's styles.scss:

```
@import "airlinedb_customtheme.scss";
.airlinedb_customtheme {
   @include airlinedb_customtheme;
 }
```

What am I missing? It looks like to me that reindeer style isn't included but I have no idea why.

EDIT:Furthermore, how can I give background color for my button and my table-row?

Comment: Can you repost your screenshot ? Are you running in production or debug mode ? Any error in logs ?

Comment: there are no error in logs and i am running it in production mode, which creenshot do you mean? aren't they visible?

Comment: Try running in debug mode. In debug mode, the css file is generated on the fly.
If it works, you have to add the generating process to your build system for the production mode. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561633/vaadin-cannot-find-themes-when-in-productionmode?rq=1

Comment: it is the same in debug mode, it's not working in production nor in debug mode

Comment: What happens if you go to your application theme in your browser ?
Should be something like: http://127.0.0.1/airlinedb/VAADIN/themes/airlinedb_custometheme/styles.css

Comment: I get a very long css source code, it seems the styles.css is generated with the reindeer included, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I have no idea of what could be wrong then. Are you sure there is no error when running in tomcat ? (during the launch or when accessing)

Comment: the only thing i constantly get in connection with the theme is not an error, an info from the server: 
`com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN
INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/themes/airlinedb_customtheme/favicon.ico] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.` I extracted the themes.jar and copied base, runo and reindeer under VAADIN before, so if this is the problem, I don't get what's missing

Comment: For the favicon it's probably "normal". You have to put your icon in your theme folder and I guess you haven't done it; but it's unrelated to your issue..

Extracting the jar files should not be necessary.. 

I just tried modifying my own theme adding an underscore in it. I have changed everything and unless I forgot something, it should works.. But it doesn't. Please try renaming your theme.

Comment: I created a new theme and applied that one, even if I don't add additional css rules, just include reindeer, it still has the same problem, the buttons and textfields are also gone just like the table. If I start clicking randomly in the browser, they sometimes appear but not quite right, or just the outlines of them, I also tried in a different browser but it's the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a suggestion but try the names without underlines.I have never seen before scss names with underlines.

Like this:

```
airlinedbCustomtheme
```

EDIT:

[Vaadin book-table](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html)

Read this at section CSS style rules.

```
.v-table {}
  .v-table-header-wrap {}
    .v-table-header {}
     .v-table-header-cell {}
      .v-table-resizer {} /* Column resizer handle. */
       .v-table-caption-container {}
 .v-table-body {}
  .v-table-row-spacer {}
   .v-table-table {}
    .v-table-row {}
     .v-table-cell-content {}
```

To change the background color of a button then you have to remove the button wrapper and background image first:

```
.v-button .v-button-wrap { 
  background-image: none !important; 
} 
.v-button { 
  background-image: none !important; 
}
```

**Don't** forget to use the `!important` modifier for the CSS!

```
.v-table { 
  background-color: red !important; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! Now the reindeer rules are included everything looks like as it should, but when I add my own rules they don't change anything, I checked the source code and the rules I've set appear there but they are still not visible on the GUI (I tried adding color to different elements for example buttons and table) Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: It might be because of the `.v-table..` is in the @mixin.Try outside the @mixin like this
`@import "../reindeer/reindeer.scss";
@mixin airlinedb_customtheme {
  @include reindeer;
}
.v-table {
    background-color: red;
  }
`

But in my opinion it's a bad habit to reference the CSS to the Vaadin generated layout names. When you will use thousands of CSS lines for a single Vaadin page it will create some very strange behaviours. Add the style name in the java section:
`table.addStyleName("yourStyleName");`
and refer in the CSS like this:
`.yourStyleName{
}`

Comment: the problem is, that I can add rules, they will be applied but only if I check the exact class name (with chrome's inspect element option) of the button for example, it won't work with either just `.v-button` nor with `addStyleName`, no matter if it's inside the `@mixin` or outside

Comment: `.v-table { background-color: red !important; } ` Oh, I forgot, that the `!important` is important :) That signs for the css compiler that it must be overwritten with your settings.

Comment: okay, it seems to be working, but how can I add colors to rows? because background color doesn't do anything on the table, well I can see the red for a sec when it's loading, but that's all then the rows are the same as before nothing changed plus I tried it with a button, `background-color` nor `color` changes color on the actual button it changes the `div` it is found in (the red comes out at the corners since the button is rounded) even though I am using `addStyleName` now

Comment: [Vaadin book-table](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html)
Read this at section CSS Style Rules, the answer is there.On the other hand, if you want to add background color for a button, then you have to remove the wrapper and the button image in the CSS:
`.v-button .v-button-wrap {
 background-image: none !important;
}

.v-button {
 background-image: none !important;
}`
Update your question,because it's not related to the original question, and you might be get warned from the administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Try extract the VAADIN/themes/reindeer directory from the vaadin jar file and add it to your VAADIN/themes/ directory inside WebContent, this way your themes/css will be served statically and your @import should work as expected.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still doesn't work, I got the same thing