# Vaadin still referencing old theme?

Tags: java, css, vaadin

So I had an existing vaadin project and I decided to import in Reindeer styles to see how they look. I compiled my theme & widget set & I decided they weren't for me.

So I removed the css import I had added and recompiled my theme & widgetset. However the styles were **still there**.

I have recompiled again & again, tried a maven clean package install on the command line, refeshed the project, tried a maven update no luck.

I have also tried deleting the server and creating it again.

Had anyone had this problem before?
Any suggestions?

(Using vaadin 7.1.2 with eclipse luna)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...

It seems running the project in debug mode has fixed this.

I spotted this answer on another stackover flow page & I figured debug mode might be the solution.

> *"When a Vaadin application is in development mode, it does the SCSS -> CSS compilation automatically when styles.css is requested and the file does not exist. In the production mode this does not happen. If styles.css exists, regardless of mode, the file is used and there is no SCSS -> CSS compilation."*

See [VAADIN cannot find themes when in productionMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561633/vaadin-cannot-find-themes-when-in-productionmode?rq=1)

Anyway hope it helps someone else!

Comment: For production you want to run the application in production mode and use precompiled styles.css file.