# How to fix, blank screen after deployment of war file

Tags: tomcat8, vaadin7, rapidclipse

I work still view month on a project with RapidClipse 4.0
I deployed on the production server several versions of the project war files. Everything worked fine.
After the last deployment I got a blank screen after loading the application URL

For the server I use a docker container with following setting:
Apache Tomcat/8.5.43, JVM: 1.8.0_222-b10, 3.10.105, amd64

My first thought was: "ok you did something wrong in your code.. turn back and every thing is fine.... :-((

It wasn't !!

I used several versions which runs fine befor.
I stopped the application, redeployed it and deleted it.
Then I deployed an older version....and once again a version older..a.s.o

Non of the versions which worked fine befor did work again.
I got every time the same result: after loading the application a blank white screen.

So far so bad:
I tried to look into ../conf/server.xml if deployment parameter is set correctly:

```
    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"                                                                                                                       
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

looked fine!

I enhanced the cache by:

$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml added following code:

```
    <Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />
```

also without success.

I tried to look in catalina.out: There is still nothing helpfull:

```
    14-Aug-2019 20:29:21.087 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/RC_07.war]
14-Aug-2019 20:29:31.190 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/RC_07.war] has finished in [10,102] ms
```

after debug in browser I got following:

```
257ms Processing time was 134ms
257msReferenced paintables: 6
283msEstablishing push connection
300msCould not load theme from http://myIP:8888/RC_07/VAADIN/themes//styles.css?v=7.7.13
310msPush connection established using long-polling
```

I searched also in the history of the docker container an found that this problem (300ms....) still persists from beginning, over all versions I deployed before.
Out of this, I assume, that this could not be the reason, too.

Or am I wrong?

I searched around this VAADIN Problem and found a lot, but I was not able to solve it. The styles.css file are still in place on the server.
I am wondering on ..../VAADIN/themes//styles.css... 
the **double slash** in error message. 
But in my code I couldn't find similar.
Also the buildpath in eclipse includes the folder structure like expected.

Now I am at the end!
I am confused, how I should go ahead to figure out the reason for this behavior, or much better to fix it.

Any idea/ help would be welcome!!

Thank you in advance
 
rgds
OpaHeinz

Comment: In meantime I installed an other tomcat docker container and a jetty container. on both container I have the same behavior.
In RapidClipse environment (uses jetty) everything works fine.

Comment: annother thing which I tried to change is switching the VAADIN production mode off, to get rid of missing themes. 
with ref to: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561633/vaadin-cannot-find-themes-when-in-productionmode?rq=1)
I entered the following code into pom.xml:
````code`
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
````code`
but also without success

Comment: I enhance also all the loglevel in tomcat to FINE.
After restart I validated following logfiles. All without success. No hint which leads to any problem.
manager.2019-08-15.log
localhost_access_log.2019-08-15.txt
localhost.2019-08-15.log
host-manager.2019-08-15.log
catalina.2019-08-15.log

Answer (score 0):

After long research, togehter with RapidClipse support we found the solution.
I had two issues: 
1) unknown how, we assume, that there was an error in the MainUI xml file.
 
    After resetting with and high of view and layout, and turning back to setting before,
 
    the page elements were visible again in design view.
2) there is a parameter for the theme under MainUI properties - misc -
    This parameter was set, but without content. This results in a code line: this.setTheme("");
    After resetting this, a deployment was possible like before.
    Everything is fine now.
Thanks again to RapidClipse support.