# How to compile additional non-theme SCSS files with Vaadin 7 and maven

Tags: sass, vaadin, vaadin7

In a `CustomComponent` of Vaadin 7, we have the annotation:

```
@StyleSheet({"../../VAADIN/themes/mytheme/views/someView.css"})
```

And it works fine while `productionMode` is `false`.

The file in question is an independent style sheet not referenced by `styles.scss`

However, once `productionMode` is set to `true`, Vaadin doesn't compile the corresponding `.scss` at run time, which is an expected behavior.

I know there is a `com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler`, but I couldn't find a documentation of how to use it with maven, so non-theme `.scss` are compiled during the build.

Below is the `vaadin-maven-plugin` usage:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.7.13</version>
    <configuration>
        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024M -Xss2048k</extraJvmArgs>
        <noServer>true</noServer>
        <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
        <compileReport>false</compileReport>
        <style>OBF</style>
        <strict>true</strict>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                <!-- <modules> <module>com.vaadin.demo.mobilemail.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet</module>
                    </modules> -->
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>resources</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                <goal>update-theme</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16563759/184201

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                <mainClass>com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/heijunka/styles.scss</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/heijunka/styles.css</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```